# How do I select a particular HTML file, and append elements to it's Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, requirejs

I am writing a program to generate HTML files.

**Method**

1.) The program will take the user's input to determine what kind of HTML file to generate (HTML, XHTML 1.1, HTML4, etc).  The program will use something like this:

```
var html5 = require('text!html/html5.html');
var html4 = require('text!html/html4.html');
var xhtml11 = require('text!html/html11.html');
```

2.) Then the user will select libraries and the program will append those libraries to the appropriate tag on the selected HTML file.  Something like:

-jQuery 1.11.3 selected

```
var jQuery1_11_3 = "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>"

$('head').append('jQuery1_11_3');
```

**Questions:**

- How can I make sure the 'head' is the  tag of the selected HTML page? And not the HTML of the DOM?
- Also I know there is a cleaner way of doing this using jQuery, any suggestions?

Comment: _"Questions:

How can I make sure the 'head' is the tag of the selected HTML page? And not the HTML of the DOM?"_  Not certain interpret this portion of Question correctly ? Try substituting `var jQuery1_11_3 = '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>'` note single quotes at beginning , end of string . jQuery `$` not appear loaded when `$('head').append('jQuery1_11_3');` called ?

Comment: I dont understand your comment, sorry.  What do you mean?

Comment: `jQuery` not appear defined at `$('head').append('jQuery1_11_3');` ? String at `"<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>"` appear to have syntax error ; double quotation marks within double quotation marks , without inner quotation marks being escaped ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking to do this as a node script and not browserside.  In that case, take a look at a library such as cheeriojs: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio.  You'll be able to create a file using core Node methods, then generate a working HTML structure that you can export to a file.  Check it out!

Comment: @guest271314 My mistake for having a typo, I wasn't typing functional code, I was moreso going for theoretical/methodical code

Comment: @lintuxvi Thanks I most certainly will check it out!! I appreciate the advice

Answer (score 0):

Note, `jQuery()` not appear defined when `.append()` called at

```
$('head').append('jQuery1_11_3');
```

?

String at

```
var jQuery1_11_3 = "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>"
```

appear to have syntax error ; double quotation marks within double quotation marks , without inner quotation marks being escaped ?

---

> How can I make sure the 'head' is the tag of the selected HTML page?
>   And not the HTML of the DOM?

Try utilizing `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]` to select `head` element ; `document.createElement()` to create `script` element , set `script` `src` to `"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"` , append `script` element to `head` element ; use `script` `onload` event to do stuff when `jQuery` loaded as property of `window` object.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.id = "jquery";
    script.onload = function() {
      // utilize `setTimeout` here if `jQuery` not defined at `onload` event
      // setTimeout(function() { 
      console.log(window.jQuery("head").find(this).attr("id"))
      // }, 1000)
    }
    script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    head.appendChild(script);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```